# Unable to add submenu under plugin menu in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm adding a plugin menu (this gets added correctly) and a submenu under it (this never shows up) like this:

```
//We'll call the action to add the menu when the plugin is loaded
add_action( "plugins_loaded", "load" );

function load()
{
    //Add us to the menu
    add_action( "admin_menu", "addToMenu" );
}

function addToMenu()
{
    //Main menu
    add_plugins_page( "My Plugin", "My Plugin", "administrator", "my-plugin", "handlePlugin" );

    //Sub Menu
    add_submenu_page( "my-plugin", "test", "test", "administrator", "my-sub-slug", "handleSub" );
}
```

The above adds the "My Plugin" but not the "test" submenu. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress does not allow 3rd level menu items by default. Code would be needed to alter how the Wordpress menu works to allow this. The workaround is to put your item *not* under plugins but at the top level.